# What do M.2 storage slot specs (AxB/C) mean?

Tags: m.2

E.g., M.2 Card Slot (storage): 22x42/80 - what means 22, 42 and 80? (That's from [NUC spec page](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/188808/intel-nuc-10-performance-kit-nuc10i7fnk.html).)

I've read that M.2 cards vary in width and length but I can't find any information what that third number above maps to - maybe it's range like from 22 to 42? Also, just to confirm 80 is length, right?

Comment: 22 42 80 are the physical width/length in millimeter of the M.2 card. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2#Form_factors_and_keying

Comment: @Robert You could post that as an answer.

Comment: @gronostaj But my comment does not cover the question completely, especially why there are two values for the width (something like minimum with and "fits also in..."?).

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit confused by this as well, but after looking at the board itself it seems 22 is the width and the 42/80 means it can use either length of M.2 card (both 22x42 and 22x80 cards). There should be another hole to move the post that screws the loose end of the card securely halfway between for using 42mm cards.